# Parse with FirebaseApp for loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know if this method is correct but I' trying to learn how to parse data content. I have this list of IDs in column A

*The IDs start from 3rd row*

886370
886371
886369
886322

```
function alfa_test() {

  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('alfatest');
  let startRow = 3;
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let numRows = lastRow  - startRow + 1;
  
  for (var i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
    
      let id = sheet.getRange(i + 3, 1).getValue();
      let url = 'http://api.scorebing.com/v4/race/view?token=&race_id=' + id;
      let response = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url);
      let dataRes = response.getData();
      let dataSF = dataRes.race.race_start_first;
      let dataL = dataRes.sp;
    
      let values = []
   
      values.push([
        dataSF.host_sp, dataSF.tie_sp, dataSF.guest_sp, dataSF.rangfen_host_sp, dataSF.rangfen_handicap, dataSF.rangfen_guest_sp,dataSF.daxiao_up_sp, dataSF.daxiao_handicap, dataSF.daxiao_low_sp,
        dataL.half_bet[0].host_sp, dataL.half_bet[0].tie_sp, dataL.half_bet[0].guest_sp, dataL.half_rangfen[0].host_sp, dataL.half_rangfen[0].handicap, dataL.half_rangfen[0].guest_sp, dataL.half_daxiao[0].up_sp, dataL.half_daxiao[0].handicap, dataL.half_daxiao[0].low_sp
      ]);
      
     sheet.getRange(i + 3, 3, rows.length, 18).setValues(values);
  }
  
}
```

**Problems**

1. *TypeError: Cannot read property 'host_sp' of undefined*

I'm not able to skip these similar errors

2. *The execution times are really long, sometimes up to 200 seconds*

**What do I expect?**

Optimize, make it faster and find the method to handle null or non-existent objects.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

With last changes, I have no output too.

```
[21-08-23 20:26:33:044 CEST] [ [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ] ]
[21-08-23 20:26:34:126 CEST] [ [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ] ]
[21-08-23 20:26:35:702 CEST] [ [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ] ]
```

I'm trying to learn javascript, my code is complete and working (badly), I ask you for some patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need something like this:

```
function alfa_test() {

  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('alfatest');
  let startRow = 3;
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let numRows = lastRow - startRow + 1;

  // get the range and get 2d array from the range
  let range = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,lastRow,1);
  let data = range.getValues().flat();

  // output array
  let output = [];

  // iterate trough 2d array
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    let id = data[i];
    let url = 'http://api.scorebing.com/v4/race/view?token=&race_id=' + id;
    
    // new row for output array
    let values = new Array(18).fill('');

    // try to get response
    try {
      let response = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url);
      let dataRes  = response.getData();
      let dataSF   = dataRes.race.race_start_first;
      let dataL    = dataRes.sp;

    values = [
        dataSF.host_sp,
        dataSF.tie_sp,
        dataSF.guest_sp,
        dataSF.rangfen_host_sp,
        dataSF.rangfen_handicap,
        dataSF.rangfen_guest_sp,
        dataSF.daxiao_up_sp,
        dataSF.daxiao_handicap,
        dataSF.daxiao_low_sp,
        dataL.half_bet[0].host_sp,
        dataL.half_bet[0].tie_sp,
        dataL.half_bet[0].guest_sp,
        // dataL.half_rangfen[0].host_sp,  // <--- empty arrays! try to skip them
        // dataL.half_rangfen[0].handicap,
        // dataL.half_rangfen[0].guest_sp,
        // dataL.half_daxiao[0].up_sp,
        // dataL.half_daxiao[0].handicap,
        // dataL.half_daxiao[0].low_sp
    ];

    // skip the row if there is no response  
    } catch(e) {}

    // add the new row to the output array
    output.push(values);

  }

  // fill the cells of the sheet with data from the output array
  sheet.getRange(startRow,3,lastRow,output[0].length).setValues(output);

}
```

But I haven't tried it. Basically all you need for speed is 2d arrays instead of `getValue`/`setValues` for every row and `try/catch` to skip the wrong responses.

### Update

Here is the clumsy but working solutions (I have no Firebase, so I used just fetch JSON):

```
function alfa_test() {

  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('alfatest');
  let startRow = 3;
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let numRows = lastRow - startRow + 1;

  // get the range and get 2d array from the range
  let range = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,1);
  let data = range.getValues().flat();

  // output array
  let output = [];

  // iterate trough 2d array
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    let id = data[i];
    let url = 'http://api.scorebing.com/v4/race/view?token=&race_id=' + id;

    let values = [];
    
    // let response = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url);
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    let dataRes  = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    let dataSF   = dataRes.race.race_start_first;
    let dataL    = dataRes.sp;

    values[0]  = dataSF.host_sp;
    values[1]  = dataSF.tie_sp;
    values[2]  = dataSF.guest_sp;
    values[3]  = dataSF.rangfen_host_sp;
    values[4]  = dataSF.rangfen_handicap;
    values[5]  = dataSF.rangfen_guest_sp;
    values[6]  = dataSF.daxiao_up_sp;
    values[7]  = dataSF.daxiao_handicap;
    values[8]  = dataSF.daxiao_low_sp;

    values[9]  = dataL.half_bet.length     > 0 ? dataL.half_bet[0].host_sp       : 'x';            
    values[10] = dataL.half_bet.length     > 0 ? dataL.half_bet[0].tie_sp        : 'x';            
    values[11] = dataL.half_bet.length     > 0 ? dataL.half_bet[0].guest_sp      : 'x';

    values[12] = dataL.half_rangfen.length > 0 ? dataL.half_rangfen[0].host_sp   : 'x';                
    values[13] = dataL.half_rangfen.length > 0 ? dataL.half_rangfen[0].handicap  : 'x';                  
    values[14] = dataL.half_rangfen.length > 0 ? dataL.half_rangfen[0].guest_sp  : 'x';

    values[15] = dataL.half_daxiao.length  > 0 ? dataL.half_daxiao[0].up_sp      : 'x';              
    values[16] = dataL.half_daxiao.length  > 0 ? dataL.half_daxiao[0].handicap   : 'x';                
    values[17] = dataL.half_daxiao.length  > 0 ? dataL.half_daxiao[0].low_s      : 'x';              

    output.push(values);

  }

  sheet.getRange(startRow,3,numRows,output[0].length).setValues(output);

}
```

It gets me this table:

[image]